# Java Multithreading in grpc

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, grpc

I have a question regarding JAVA-MULTITHREADING.

I have a jetty webapp with an grpc-streaming-client. everything is fine but how can I built up a model for getting the streaming data?

The webapp is build up with jsf. in that i have a controller which invokes a handler class for starting the stream:

```
    public void startStream(){
    if(streamHandler!=null & activatedStream == false){
        streamHandler.startStreamClient();          
        activatedStream = true;
    }else{
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                "Could not initialize the StreamHandler and Client Class or a Stream still runs. Please check the logs.", "Stream is running: "+String.valueOf(activatedStream));
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

This method simple starts the client and the stream.

```
    public void startStreamClient(){
    log.info("Calling startMethod of Handler............");
    CountDownLatch finishLatch;
    if(this.client.isChannelShutdown()& this.client!=null){

        this.client=new StreamClient(this.serverHost, this.serverPort);

        try{
            finishLatch = this.client.imageStream(this.startRequest);
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.warn("Error while starting the imageStream: "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }else{
        finishLatch = client.imageStream(this.startRequest);
    }
}
```

The Implementation of checking CountDownLatch is still missing. But it does not matter in this case.

The Responses comes here: The onNext()-Method is giving the streamed Data:

```
public CountDownLatch imageStream(StreamRequest request){

    log.info("Calling imageStream-asnychStub...............");

    CountDownLatch finish = new CountDownLatch(1);

    /**
     *  The asyncStub is calling the rpc-Function with a new StreamObserver for the given Responses from the Server.
     */
    StreamObserver<StreamRequest> requestOberserver = asyncStub.streamImagaData(new StreamObserver<StreamResponse>() {

        /**
         * The onNext Method is getting the imageDate, if it is send
         */
        @Override
        public void onNext(StreamResponse response) {
            System.out.println("Data-Input: "+response.getImageData().length());
        }

        /**
         * The onError Method is getting an Exception Object if it is thrown
         */
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            log.warn("Bidirectional Stream with Server an Client: "+t.getLocalizedMessage(), t);
        }           

        /**
         * The onCompleted is for ending the Stream and reduces the CountDownLatch by one
         */
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            log.info("Bidirectional Streaming has finished....");
            finish.countDown();
        }
    });

    /**
     * This Block is for sending a StreamRequest to the Server.
     */
    try{
        log.info("Sending a Streaming-Request to Server with State: "+request.getStreamState().name());
        requestOberserver.onNext(request);
    }catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        log.warn("Error sending requst to Server: "+ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
        requestOberserver.onError(ex);
    }
    requestOberserver.onCompleted();

    return finish;
}
```

The Imagedata is simple printed on Screen. I tried to build up a consumer-producer-model but failed because the response returns in an innertyp of StreamObserver.

How can I get this Data in realtime. Do I have to create an official implementation of the StreamObserver? Or where do I have to place the additional Threads? Are Threads the only choice? Do i need some callables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You also need to call `finish.countDown()` in the `onError` callback.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by implmenting the observer-pattern.

The ManagedBean becam the Observer of the StreamClient.